# select columns where one from columns contains value is it possible ? in linq

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way to query where one of the columns contains a value?

This is my code:

```
public JsonResult FindCustomer(string value)
{
    var result= new SelectList(db.Customers.Where(t => (t.PersonalMail.Contains(value) ||
    t.BusinessMail.Contains(value)
    || t.ContactName.Contains(value) ||
    t.BusinessName.Contains(value) || t.Phone.Contains(value) ||
    t.DirectPhone.Contains(value)), "ID", "PersonalMail");
    return Json(jj);
}
```

Maybe it is possible to do something like this:

```
var result= new SelectList(db.Customers.Where(t => (Each column).Contains(value)), "ID", "PersonalMail");
```

Comment: what is ur Requirements. question is not in proper

Comment: To query where one of the columns contains a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public JsonResult FindCustomer(string value)
{
    var Customers = db.Customers.ToList();
    var result = new SelectList(db.Customers.Where(t =>
        t?.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => //for all columns of a row where...
            (x.PropertyType==typeof(string)) && // it does have the same type
            x.GetValue(t, null) != null && // the value should not be null
             x.GetValue(t, null).ToString().Contains(value)) // the value should be equal
        ?? false), // if t is null, than skip it
        "ID", "PersonalMail");

    return Json(jj);
}
```

Would do the trick. If you do want to exclude some columns, add them to the `ANY` clause:

```
.Any(x =>  x.GetValue(t, null) != null && !x.Name.Equals("BusinessMail") && (x.PropertyType==typeof(string)) && x.GetValue(t, null).ToString().Contains(value))
```

---

For selecting the value of the first property containing the value, add the following after `"PersonalMail")`:

```
.Select(t=>t.GetType().GetProperties().First(x=> // get the first porperty
    x.GetValue(t, null).Equals(value) // where the value equals the searched one
 ).GetValue(t, null)); // And select the value of that property.
```

If you do want to get the property instead of the value, than remove `.GetValue(t, null)`. You could also use `Where` instead of `Any` and will return a list of all properties containing that value. (Note, that it will return a collection filled with [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)!)

Comment: What if there are other string properties in the type not participating in the test ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht `what is the best way To query where one of the columns contains a value` does tell me, that there is no other value inside the table that would not participate in _the test_.

Comment: i get this error  'PropertyInfo[]' does not contain a definition for 'test' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyInfo[]' could be found

Comment: maybe but you should at least explain it in the answer ; as future readers with a similar but different problem could try that without success because they don't know that part

Comment: you can try to fix this problem
You sure this is the word test

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 I have edited the answer. It does now also include an exclude method and I do also fixed the `test` error. (As you could guess - I have used it for testing :P)

Comment: i get this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I am very grateful for the effort and enjoy your thinking direction

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 it should now work. I did not recognize, that the `GetProperties` returns `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 There where also some errors with `.GetValue()` -> fixed!

Comment: The OP is using Entity Framework, and as the error message states, there is no SQL translation available for calls to `.GetProperties`. If you want to do something like this, you can start with the type, and create an expression that calls `.Contains` on every string property in the type.

Comment: It seems to me a good way
I fall when t is null " x.GetValue(t, null)"

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 But if you are querying against Entity Framework, there is no need for actual null checking. What you are passing into `Where` is not  compiled into runnable code, but rather into an expression tree. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linq/842/getting-started-with-linq/24398/linq-methods-and-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet).

Comment: It works for me please edit your answer and I will mark it as an answer to true

 var Customers = db.Customers.ToList();

            var result = Customers.Where(t =>
    t.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x =>
    x.PropertyType == typeof(string)
    && x.GetValue(t, null) != null &&
         x.GetValue(t, null).ToString().Contains((value)))).ToList();

Comment: is possible to select only the propety is contains the value ?

Comment: like this .Select( op => new { Value = op.GetValue(t, null).ToString(),t.ID }))

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 If you put in a `.ToList` it will work, because you are now querying a local in-memory collection of `Customer` objects. But calling `.ToList` means that you are actually loading all the customers from the database into memory. This may not be a good thing -- if your database has a million records and you only need five, calling `.ToList` will load all the million records into memory.

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 updated the answer. Note that you do not have to think about null values, because they have been _destroyed_ by the `Where` clause. :)

Comment: English a little hard for me but I think your Note wrong

Comment: I want an object with a parameter containing the search instead of "PersonalMail" and customerID

like this
 var ttut = (from t in result4
             from y in t.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x =>
     x.PropertyType == typeof(string)
     && x.GetValue(t, null) != null)
             where y.GetValue(t, null).ToString().Contains((value))
             select new { result = y.GetValue(t, null).ToString(),t.ID });

Comment: The second part of my answer tells you, how you could create a collection of PropertyInfo collections. Theoretically iterate through the (above) collection and create an new objects from the PropertyInfo collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure it's better or worth it but (assuming all is the same type) you can do :

```
var result =
    new SelectList (
        db
        .Customers
        .Where (t => new[] {
            t.PersonalMail,
            t.BusinessMail,
            t.ContactName,
            t.BusinessName
            t.Phone,
            t.DirectPhone
        }.Any (s => s.Contains (value))), "ID", "PersonalMail");
```

But I think it would be better to have a method somewhere (possibly in the class from which `t` comes) which leverage that something like

```
bool CheckContains (TypeOfT t, string value)
{
    return t.PersonalMail.Contains (value)
        || t.BusinesMail.Contains (value)
        || t.ContactName.Contains (value)
        || t.BusinessName.Contains (value)
        || t.Phone.Contains (value)
        || t.DirectPhone.Contains (value);
}

// ...
var result = new SelectList (db.Customers.Where (t => CheckContains (t, value)), "ID", "PersonalMail");
```

Comment: i think is impossible to use function inside a query

Comment: Sure you can ; you can even use a method group if the signature match (would have required to use curryfication here to make it work though and that's not an idiomatic thing in C#)

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 If you are querying against a local in-memory collection -- IEnumerable<T> -- then you can use functions inside the query. But if you are querying using IQueryable<T> and a LINQ provider that performs some transformation, then you can only use functions that the provider recognizes. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linq/842/getting-started-with-linq/24398/linq-methods-and-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet).

Comment: It appears that the OP is indeed using Entity Framework, and querying against `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **let**

```
var result = new SelectList((from t in db.Customers
                             let values = new[]
                             {
                                    t.PersonalMail,
                                    t.BusinessMail,
                                    t.ContactName,
                                    t.BusinessName,
                                    t.Phone,
                                    t.DirectPhone
                             }
                             where values.Any(v => v.Contains(value))
                             select t), "ID", "PersonalMail");
```

Comment: Where does `c` comes in `select c` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want it short, you can try this:
 `db.Customers.Where(t => (t.PersonalMail + t.BusinesMail + t.ContactName).Contains(value)`
but it's may not efficiency.

Comment: What if the end of one part combined with the start of the next make it equal to the searched value ? the value is then contained in the full thing but not in any part

Comment: you can add a separator

Comment: Maybe, but that implies to know what `value` is (or can be) to be sure the separator can't contain it (or the different part)

Comment: if that you need use array like other answers mentioned, it's depends on you real situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to build the appropriate expression. Add the following `using` statements.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;
```

Something like this:

```
static Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> ExpressionBuilder(string phrase) {
    //We are trying to set up the equivalent of this:
    //  x => x.PersonMail == phrase || x.BusinessMail == phrase || x.ContanctName == ...
    //The lambda expression has a single parameter
    //  x =>
    //In the body of the lambda, for each string property on Customer, we want to call the 
    //property on the parameter, and then check if it is equal to the phrase
    //  x.PersonMail == phrase
    //We then want to combine each result into an ||
    //  x.PersonMail == phrase || x.BusinessMail == phrase ...

    //Define an expression representing the parameter
    var prm = Parameter(typeof(Customer));

    //Get all the string properties
    var stringProps = typeof(Customer).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        //For each property, create an expression that represents reading the property, and 
        //comparing it to phrase as a constant (as if we had written the literal value into 
        //the query)
        .Select(x => Equal(MakeMemberAccess(prm, x), Constant(phrase)));

    //Combine the equals expressions using ||
    Expression expr = stringProps.Aggregate((prev, x) => Or(prev, x));

    //Wrap the body in a lambda expression of the appropriate type
    return Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(expr, prm);
}
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
//qry is IQueryable<Customer>
qry = qry.Where(ExpressionBuilder("test"));
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 Updated.

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 Added comments